# "Nullable object must have a value" error in Blazor InputNumber Component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to use a nullable property with InputNumber built-in Blazor Component. When I use the property with @bind-Value attribute, it works fine. But when I am trying to use it like below, it is giving error 'Nullable object must have a value'

```
 <InputNumber class="form-control" ValueExpression="@(() => model.Amount)"
                             Value="@(model.Amount)"
                             ValueChanged="@((double? value) => AmountUpdated(value))" />
```

I have to implement some custom logic on ValueChanged event which is why I am trying to use bind values this way.

Comment: You'll have to show more code than that.  At the very least, show your `model` class and the `AmountUpdated` signature.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this

```
 ValueChanged="@((value) => AmountUpdated(value))"
```